# Text in Outlook doesn't use line-height

Tags: css, outlook, html-email

I'm creating a Email with Html and I stumbled upon an issue with Outlook 2010. Here is my code:

```
<td background="images/11-text-1--alpha-d3c29e.jpg" 
bgcolor="#d3c29e" width="514" height="460"  valign="top">        
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" 
    style="width:514px;height:460px;">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="images/11-text-1--alpha-d3c29e.jpg" color="d3c29e" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
    <![endif]-->
        <p style="margin:0;padding:0;font-family:'Courier New',Courier,monospace;
        font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;color:#000000;line-height:15px;">
            #TEXT
        </p>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>     </v:textbox>   </v:rect>   <![endif]-->
</td>
```

now I want to change the line-height from the text, but when I change it in my p tag, it wont do it, but also if I put it in the td and/or the MSO exeption it wouldn't do the trick for Outlook. Is there any way to make this work, or does anyone know a workaround for Outlook?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use the mso style "mso-line-height-rule". This is used to force Outlook to respect the line height rule. Please note this needs to be added PRIOR to the declared line-height or it will not work.  See below:

```
<td background="images/11-text-1--alpha-d3c29e.jpg" 
bgcolor="#d3c29e" width="514" height="460"  valign="top" style="margin:0;padding:0;font-family:'Courier New',Courier,monospace; font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;color:#000000;mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height:15px;">        
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" 
    style="width:514px;height:460px;">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="images/11-text-1--alpha-d3c29e.jpg" color="d3c29e" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
    <![endif]-->   
            #TEXT
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>     </v:textbox>   </v:rect>   <![endif]-->
</td>
```

Comment: YES! Finally! Thanks so so much! This works perfectly! I worked on this for almost 4h now and i couldn't find this tag anywhere! Now I'll never make this mistake again! Thanks! ;)

Comment: yeah it is a hidden gem. One of the few times MS actually had a fix for one of their 'quirks'.

Comment: Haha yes, I worked on that issue with my developing buddy, who is working on Html Emails for a couple of years now and he even didn't know this fix. Thanks again! :D

Comment: This worked for me when the line-height styles were applied to the <td> element. It did not work when the styles were applied to a <p> within the <td>

Answer (score 2):

First of all, styling "p" tag is out  of date, and some mail clients reject that (such as Outlook). I've encountered such problmems previously.

What I do recommend is that you should mainly style "td" tags. If you have other texts in this particular section insert "span" tag, and then some styling to it (but try to not override things you've styled in "td" tag.

Down below you have an example:

```
<td style="background-color: #2e3242;color:#ffffff; padding: 10px 0;
border-radius: 5px; font-size:15px; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
 line-height: 20px; text-align: center;width:28%; vertical-align: middle">
                                    Lorem Ipsum</td>
```

And here with a span

```
<td width="548" style="color:#a8796b; font-size:14px; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 
sans-serif; line-height: 18px; text-align: center; 
width:548px; vertical-align: middle">
<span style="font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif; font-weight: 300;
font-size: 16px;line-height: 30px;color:#a8796b">
Lorem Ipsum </span><br>
                                    Best Regards,<br>Lorem Ipsum
                                </td>
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer! But unfortunately is styling on the p tag not the problem. Like I stated in the question I tried styling on the td instead, wich also didn't work. And according to [this](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) source, line-height should work on either.

Comment: Have you tried giving td atrribute background-image:"images/11-text-1--alpha-d3c29e.jpg" ?

Comment: Yes I did, and both wouldn't show in mso, that why I exepted it to show a rect with the exact same size with the img as src

Comment: I've tested your code, and after deleting comments and valign atrribute it has worked. Maybe that could help you.

Comment: If you deleted the comments, it wouldn't show the img in the background. That's what the comments are for

Comment: Actually deleting them, worked for me ;) But nvm, hope some1 else can help you. :)